# Credit card type variables for paypal REST API

Tags: paypal

Is there a list someplace in the Paypal rest API documentation that lists the string i am supposed to provide for the credit card type? I know one is "visa" but what about the others?

Comment: I disagree. The question asked exactly what i needed or two people would not have answered the question . Could i please have my points back?

Comment: your question is pretty clear, and the answers useful. i myself came her today with the same problem and got the correct. that said stackoverflow is full of bullies who love to close questions. don't hope for it to be reopened. you have my upvote though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card)

> **Key:** type
>
> **Type:** string
>
> **Description:** Credit card type. Valid types are: visa, mastercard, discover, amex

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how the heck i overlooked that so many freaking times.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Visa / Delta / Electron
> MasterCard / Eurocard
> Maestro
> American Express.
> ```

Comment: This should answer your question:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#creditcard-object

Credit card type. Valid types are: visa, mastercard, discover, amex