# International Credit and Debit card authorization API

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I want to validate the international Debit and Credit card. First Authorize and Capture the amount for future. Please let me know Which API is best to support All types of card.
I have reviewed the Authorize.net. but let me know whether it support cards like Maestro, UnionPay Cards. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link will help you about this. In my application I referred this one

[Credit card type variables for paypal REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017005/credit-card-type-variables-for-paypal-rest-api)